# oracle group by using rank

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

TableOne

```
Id1| Level     |Type|Survey Nr
--------------------------------
  1| Level 1   |A   |1  
  2| Level 2   |A   |1
  3| Level 3   |A   |1
  4| All Levels|A   |1   
 ------------------------------- 
  5| Level 1   |B   |1 
  6| Level 2   |B   |1
  7| Level 4   |B   |1
 -------------------------------- 
  8| Level 1   |A   |2 
  9| Level 2   |A   |2
 10| Level 3   |A   |2
 11| All Levels|A   |2
```

I want to group my data by  type and survey Nr an the output of my query to be

```
1. All levels   |A   |1
2. Level 1      |B   |1 
3. Level 2      |B   |1
4. Level 4      |B   |1
5. All Levels   |A   |2
```

So when my subgroup Type/survey nr  have level "All Levels" i will only display that record  like in case A -1 and A2 else i want to display all records like in case B-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the `RANK()` function and a `CASE` statement:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT "Id1","Lev","Type","Survey_Nr"
                    ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY "Type","Survey_Nr" ORDER BY CASE WHEN "Lev" = 'All Levels' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS RN
             FROM Table1)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY "Id1"
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8944e/16/0)

`RANK()` will assign a rank value to each set indicated in the `PARTITION BY` clause, and the `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY` is used to set all values of Lev into one of two categories, giving preference to the "All Levels" values.  Running this without the `WHERE` clause will help you see how the `RANK()` function is working.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just UNION ALL the data where you have the string `'All Levels'` to the data where it doesn't exist within that group. I've effectively assumed that your table is unique on LEVEL, TYPE and SURVEY_NR.

```
with base_data as (
 select a
   from the_table
        )
select level, type, survey_nr
  from base_data
 where level = 'All Levels'
 union all
select level, type, survey_nr
  from base_data
 where not exists ( select 1
                      from base_data
                     where level = 'All Levels'
                       and type = x.type
                       and survey_nr = x.survey_nr
                           )
```

Please note that LEVEL is normally an invalid name for a column; it's worth changing it.

Comment: Column name it's training level and data are numeric like 1 ,2 ,3 and All levels are represented as null .Yes table is unique on LEVEL, TYPE and SURVEY_NR .

Comment: So, this should work then @jonny. You'll obviously have to change the WHERE clauses to be `where level is null` though...